# Getting sum of numeric values in a string object in Dataframe

Tags: python, string, split, sum

I have a string column in dataframe(train_2) like this:

```
  ID  Str_1
  id1  AA: 2, RR: 3,FF: 40
  id2  RR: 6,BB:
  id3  Blank
  id4  GG:20,AA:20
```

Expected output

```
ID Sum
id1 45
id2 6
id3 0
id4 40
```

I tried something like this for iterating over rows, but its throwing me Keyerror 5:

```
w1 = train_2['Str_1']
w1 = w1.str.split(',')

main = []
for i in np.arange(train_2.shape[0]):
    d1 = w1[i]
    nest = []
    nest = [re.sub(pattern = '.*\:', repl=' ', string= d1[k]) for k in list(np.arange(len(d1)))]
    main.append(nest)
```

How can i achieve this? is there any easier method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `pandas`, you can use `str.extractall` to get all the numbers from each row, and then sum the numbers up:

```
train_2['sum'] = train_2['Str_1'].str.extractall('([0-9]+)').astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()

train_2.fillna(0)

#    ID Str_1                sum
#0  id1 AA: 2, RR: 3,FF: 40  45.0
#1  id2 RR: 6,BB:            6.0
#2  id3 Blank                0.0
#3  id4 GG:20,AA:20          40.0
```